# Input an image from some saved location on computer

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

I have a draw function

```
public void drawBoard(Graphics g) {
  int height = this.getHeight();
  int width = this.getWidth();
  int dx = width / 7;
  int dy = height / 6;

  for (int x = 0, row = 0; x <= width && row < gameboard.length; row++, x += dx) {
    for (int col = 0, y = 0; y <= height&& col < gameboard[0].length; y += dy, col++) {
      if (gameboard[row][col] == 0) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(y, x, dy, dx);
      } else if (gameboard[row][col] == 1) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(y, x, dy, dx);
      } else if(gameboard[row][col] == 1){

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(y, x, dy, dx);
      } else if(gameboard[row][col]==3){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==4){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==5){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==6){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==7){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==8){

      }else if(gameboard[row][col]==9){

      }

    }
  }

}
```

However for when gameboard[row][col]=3,4,...9 I want it to change that slot into a picture downloaded from the web. How do I do that?

I would prefer to do it without a URL definition and simply a get Document like thing in html where I have the photos saved in a file

Comment: Are the images downloaded from the web a) Stored in a local file - i.e. the download is done outside your program / manually b) on the web and should be downloaded from a URL by your program?

Comment: the download is done outside of the program. I also believe I would need to re-size the photos to fit the place where they are going into

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get your image as a BufferedImage.  I suggest using the [ImageIO class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html):

```
String imageFileName = "myTestFile.jpg"
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(((new File(imageFileName)).toURI()).toURL());
```

Next, you want to draw your image using the [Graphics.drawImage() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).  Your comment indicates that you think you'll need to scale the image, so use the appropriate drawImage method to do that.  Using your Graphics object g from your code above, this might look like::

```
int oldWidth = img.getWidth();
int oldHeight = img.getHeight();
int newWidth = 10; //You decide this...
int newHeight = 10; //You decide this too...
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oldWidth, newWidth, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
```

Oracle themselves have an applet which demonstrates the code for this approach, along with a number of other common operations you might want to do on images in their [ImageDrawingApplet.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/ImageDrawingApplet.java) code